# Receive and Print a Twilio SMS with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sms, twilio, twilio-api

For clarification, I don't want to reply to the SMS. Every tutorial or document I've looked at is about setting up a port to listen on.

What I'm trying to do is just get the SMS and print it. I can send them fine and without problems.

Here is my sending function, and it works.

```
def send():
  message = client.messages \
      .create(
           body=sendMSG,
           from_='MY_TWILIO_NUMBER',
           to='MY_PERSONAL_NUMBER'
       )
  print(message.sid)
```

How would you receive an SMS without Flask? Is there a way to do something similar to this method below just for receiving?

```
def receive():
  message = client.messages \
      .recieve(
           from_='MY_PERSONAL_NUMBER',
           to='MY_TWILIO_NUMBER'
       )
  print(message.sid)
```

Comment: How are you getting these SMS messages?  Is this inside a webhook, or something else?

Comment: @TimmSimpkins I'm trying to avoid using a webhook.

Comment: The best way to receive messages as they arrive is via the webhook. Otherwise you can request them from the API as Timm has posted below.

Answer (score 3):

I have not personally tried to get SMS messages from the logs before, always getting it directly through a webhook, but from what I see, it appears the command you might be looking for is `list()`.  You can add filters, as shown in [the API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message#list-filters), and there are three filtering options.  You can filter by DateSent, To, or From.

I have not tried this, but it would seem that the way to use this would be the following (adjusted from the code they supply):

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

messages = client.messages.list(from='MY_PERSONAL_NUMBER', to='MY_TWILIO_NUMBER')

for record in messages:
    print(record.sid)
```

If that doesn't work, the variables they use are actually capitalized "To" and "From", so you might try that.

After looking at that a bit, you might be looking more for this:

```
received = client.messages.list(to='MY_TWILIO_NUMBER')
sent = client.messages.list(from='MY_PERSONAL_NUMBER')
```

That will separate out those sent to you, and those sent from you

Comment: Thanks for your answer here. It saved a lot of my time.